# File Save reading correctly but throwing errors that give no description

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a program that takes data from one file, parses it, and prints it to a second file. First I open the first file with the file dialog object but then when I try to select a file to save as my program crashes.

```
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
lblContinue:
    With fd
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select a file to edit."
        .InitialFileName = "C:\Program Files (x86)\AceCooler32\aceuser\"
    End With

    If fd.Show <> 0 Then
        sFileName = fd.SelectedItems(1)
    End If

    If sFileName = "" Then Exit Sub

    sFileName2 = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(, , , "Save File As: ")

    Open sFileName For Input As #1

    Debug.Print sFileName
    Debug.Print sFileName2

    On Error GoTo lblError:


    Open sFileName2 For Output As #2
```

The thing that gets me is that the Debug.print for sFileName2 shows the correct name for the file I selected, but then throws an error and crashes my program. The on error statement was added so I wouldn't have to force-kill excel every time I tested the code. There is no error text or popup, it just freezes Excel.

Here is my On Error code:

```
    ' Resume

    On Error GoTo -1

    On Error GoTo lblError2:

    Debug.Print Err.Description
    Debug.Print Err.HelpContext

    MsgBox ("You must save using a different filename." & Err.Description)
    Close #1
    Close #2
    GoTo lblContinue:
```

The description given by the Err.Description is blank

Comment: Not sure if it will fix your issue, but you should use [`FreeFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/freefile-function) instead of a hard-coded number.

Comment: To use that I would just add variable like fileNum1 and fileNum2 and set them to FreeFile before opening? Such as filenum1 = FreeFile?

Comment: Yes as the code snippet in the docs shows.

Comment: Implemented the changes, problem remains. Thank you for the the tip though.